# joining sentences from a list in python3

Tags: python, regex, list, join, gensim

I am trying to join a lists of appended sentences into a large a string text object so that I can use it as an input for the Gensim summarize module. However, when I try to do this, it says the input sentences are less than 2. But when I run a split on the text, I see multiple sentences but it counts each sentence once instead of the total of sentences together. And the variable r is a string type object. I would like to concatenate the sentences together into one large string so it can be read through the Gensim summarize module.

**Sample Code:**

```
import re
ruling_corpora  = re.findall("\.?([^\.].\*?I find[^\.]*\. |[^\.]*$In sum[^\.]*\. |[^\.]*$agree[^\.]*\.)", tokenized, re.I |re.DOTALL |re.M)[1:-1]

for r in ruling_corpora:                                   
    print(type(r))
    rc= ''.join(r)
    print(summarize(rc))
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
raise ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")
ValueError: input must have more than one sentence
```

Here is an example of my input I want to summarize with the Gensim summarizer. The numbers underneath each string represent the count of sentences ending in periods:

```
####Beginning of File### LUMB65.BL23607963.xml
Background Content: ANDERSON INITIAL DECISIONOn January 13, 2015, the appellant filed this appeal arguing that the agency's decision not to renew his term limited appointment which expired on January 28, 2015, is in error.  

 For the reasons discussed below, this appeal is DISMISSED for lack of jurisdiction without a hearing.
1
There is nothing in the agreement that curtails the agency's ability not to extend the term appointment. 
 IdIn reviewing the appellant's arguments, the appellant fails to establish that the Board has jurisdiction to review the agency's decision not to renew his time-limited appointment at issue in this appeal.
 Following a review of the record evidence, I find that the appellant has failed to non-frivolously allege Board jurisdiction over this appeal on any basis.
 Accordingly, this appeal must be dismissed for lack of jurisdiction.
1
####End of File### LUMB65.BL23607963.xml
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/summarization/summariser.html#gensim.summarization.summarizer.summarize) (emphasis mine):

> The input should be a string, and must be longer than INPUT_MIN_LENGTH
>   sentences for the summary to make sense. The text will be split into
>   sentences using the split_sentences method in the
>   gensim.summarization.texcleaner module. **Note that newlines divide
>   sentences.**

Try using `rc = '\n'.join(r)`.  You could also debug by calling `gensim.summarization.texcleaner.split_sentences` to check the result.

Additionally your regular expression does not match your given input and even if it did, you discard the only two results with `[1:-1]`.  Try this instead:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], re.findall('([^.]*?(I find|In sum|agree)[^.]*\.)', tokenized, re.I | re.DOTALL | re.M))
["\n1\nThere is nothing in the agreement that curtails the agency's ability not to extend the term appointment.", '\n Following a review of the record evidence, I find that the appellant has failed to non-frivolously allege Board jurisdiction over this appeal on any basis.']
```

You may want to process out the stand-alone numbers first since they show up in the match.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the rc = '\n'.join(r) but it seems to split the words down vertically rather than together. But I will try to call the textcleaner method from Gensim library

Comment: Please create an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your input (i.e. value of `tokenized`).

Comment: The sample input is inside my post. It is underneath the line: ####Beginning of File### LUMB65.BL23607963.xml

Comment: Your regular expression does not match that input at all.  If you removed the trailing space in the `I find` you would get one match but you would throw it away by using `[1:-1]` at the end.

Comment: I made those adjustments. And thanks for your assistance. However, when I still join my matched sentences, for some reason it doesn't consider the joined strings as a total string but each line is counted seperately. So for instance, if I have 4 joined sentences, when I count the number of sentences, it counts each sentence as its own individual sentence rather combined together.

Comment: Oh yea, I am reading and parsing the XML file in binary mode. I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: and the value of tokenized is a string object that combines all the tokenized text retrieved from the xml input file